# Styling a result set

Tags: html, css

Perhaps this is not the proper place to ask this question, if that is the case, please direct me to the correct venue.

I'm looking for research, guides, any kind of information pertaining to the structuring and styling of results sets; data which comes back from a search, or when looking at content in a list view.

Links would be appreciated, but opinion and commentary are also valued.

Answer (score 2):

- http://icant.co.uk/csstablegallery/
- http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/08/13/top-10-css-table-designs/
- http://www.noupe.com/css/21-fresh-ajax-css-tables.html

Comment: A lot of these seem good for strictly tabular data. Anything for more verbose data, think along the lines of search results, displaying roughly a paragraph + title + additional small data.

Answer (score 0):

The [CSS table gallery](http://icant.co.uk/csstablegallery/) may prove useful.